# Sharepoint Workflow is still recursive on item change even with sp2

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, recursion, workflow

I have a basic workflow programmed in Visual Studio 10 for a sharepoint site.  It fires on a list item change or creation.  The workflow basically sends an email, changes the value of one of the item fields and updates the field.

The problem:  Before sp2, this should create a recursive workflow where the workflowproperties.Item.Update re-calls the items on-change event and restarts the workflow and I end up with a bunch of emails in my inbox.

From my research, sp2 was supposed to eliminate this but it seems to be still happening to me.

From what I've researched, my version number 12.0.0.6421 is from SP2 so I shouldn't be getting this problem.

Any ideas how to stop the recursion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disableeventfiring is your friend when updating list items.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it!  I'm quite new to sp wf's < 10hrs so I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I had to create a new class to that inherits SPItemEventReceiver, then two methods to enable or disable the event fireing such as: this.DisableEventFiring() then create a new instance in the workflow and wrap obj.DisableFire() and obj.EnableFire() around the item.Update().